# Incompatible types when trying to input data into an array

Tags: java, arrays, input, java.util.scanner, incompatibletypeerror

I'm having problems with inputting data interactively into arrays. I'm trying to use the nextLine method to add a set of 12 names into the array, but when I compile at the end of line 12 it gives me the error "Incompatible Types".

```
public class nextLineArray {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        char names[] = new char[12];
        System.out.println("Enter the 12 names: ");

        for(int i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
            names[i] = input.nextLine();
        }

        System.out.println(names);
    }
}
```

Comment: What does `input.nextLine()` returns? What can your `names` array contain?

Comment: Do you really want to represent names by individual chars? I think you want your array to be of type String, not char.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the Scanner.nextLine() returns a String, not a char

Try changing

```
char names[]=new char[12];
```

To

```
String names[] = new String[12];
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you use Char for storing names?? Use Strings instead.

And also nextLine() returns a String not a char. So the error.

Just FYI... you can even use next() to get the input from console if you doesnt want the input to be null or empty. nextLine() takes even an empty string as input. Try next()